# Do I need PCR test to enter Switzerland by vehicle from Germany?

Tags: covid-19

I see that PCR test is required to enter Switzerland by plane. Nothing mentioned for those who travel by vehicle from a low-risk country.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The [Federal Office of Public Health](https://www.bag.admin.ch/bag/en/home/krankheiten/ausbrueche-epidemien-pandemien/aktuelle-ausbrueche-epidemien/novel-cov/empfehlungen-fuer-reisende/quarantaene-einreisende.html) (BAG/OFSP) has the information you need.

As of June 3, the last German states (Land Sachsen and Thüringen) are removed from the high-risk list. But the situation can again change and states may be added back.

From a low-risk country/region, you may enter by private vehicle, bike or as a pedestrian without particular conditions. If you take a bus or train, an entry form needs to be filled in. If you are taking a flight, a negative test is also necessary. Exemptions apply for persons coming from border regions, fully vaccinated persons within last six months, persons who recovered from COVID-19 in the past 6 months and other grounds (see the link for more detailed information).